# What does `*p+++c&63` mean in C++?

Tags: c

I'm a fan of the [Hitman](https://hitman.com/) game, a stealth-action assassination game.

In the cinematic for the latest challenge, I spotted the [following code-like snippet](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YFKTMgP7XpisDDH87). I have no C++ experience and no C-tools installed on my system, so I tried copying it into a REPL [here](https://repl.it), but consistently got errors*

Here's my transcription of the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int,char**a){for(char*p="25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-0?0&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_.",c=a[1][0];*p;putc(c=(*p+++c&63)+32,stdout));}
```

(Reformatted-for-readability later in this post).

So far as I can tell, this is meant to be a cypher ("take each character of `cipher`, pass it through a transformation, and print it out"), but I can neither get this to execute, nor understand it enough to translate it to a language that I know like Python: I have *no* idea what `*p+++c&63` means. My guess is that it should be broken up as follows:

- `*p++` - take the next character of `*p`...
- `+` - ...and add it(s integer representation) to...
- `c` - ...the previously-set value of `c` (either from the previous iteration of the loop, or from initialization as `c=a[1][0]`)...
- `&63` - ...do something? Looks like a [bit-wise operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/)?
- `+32` - add 32 to the result

Additionally, the initial value of `a` seems to be the decryption key - but I've scoured the rest of the video, and can't find any hints as to what it's meant to be.

I tried to translate this to Python (iterating over all letters and numbers as the key) as follows:

```
import string

cipher = "25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-0?0&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_."

def printout(c):
  plaintext = ""
  for p in cipher:
    c = chr(ord(p) + ((ord(c) & 63)) + 32)
    plaintext += c
  print(plaintext)

for c in string.letters + string.digits:
  printout(c)
```

But each line of the resultant output is mostly garbage.

What am I missing? Have I mistranslated (C++) `c=(*p+++c&63)+32` to (Python) `c = chr(ord(p) + ((ord(c) & 63)) + 32)` (within a for-loop, advancing `p` to the next character), or do I just need to cast my net wider for the decryption key?

---

Reformatted the original code a little for readability:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int,char**a) {
  for(
    char*p="25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-0?0&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_.", 
      c=a[1][0];
    *p;
    putc(c=(*p+++c&63)+32,stdout)
  );}
```

* including, but not limited to, an error that `main` should return `int`, and that `ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'`

Comment: this is the most interesting existential problem someone ever had :) +1

Comment: Pretty sure this is intended to be a [tag:c] snippet since it uses `<stdio.h>` and not `<cstdio>`, which would be one character shorter. That's relevant since this is clearly an attempt at [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Dunno if it's golfing, but it is obfuscated. Without knowing what a is it's fairly pointless. `c&63` clears all but the bottom 6 bits, and adding 32 could be lowercasing an uppercase letter or adding the value to the space character as an offset into the ascii table. *shrug*

Comment: Mind your operator precedence. Even in Python, `+` has higher precedence than `&`.

Comment: this isn't c: `void main(int,char**a)` no parameter.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/HiTMAN/comments/b729s2/i_decrypted_the_code_in_the_elusive_target/

Comment: @RetiredNinja: You don’t need to know `a`, there are only 64 options.

Comment: right! I have deobfuscated this code and it doesn't work. prints nothing. it's not C++ because you cannot use `char *` to point to literal string (maybe with MSVC) and it isn't c because of missing argument...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Need to pass the program an argument. `o` gives the first bit, `m` gives the second.

Comment: @Ry- I know, I brute forced it before googling it because there's a typo in this transcription. https://ideone.com/dIQzbx Once I had the correct string it worked fine. Presumably the code is wrong, because argv[0][0] would be the most likely way to get a `/` without needing an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does `*p+++c&63` mean in C++?

1. `p++` Postfix increment. Increments pointer `p` to the next character; result is pointer value before increment.
2. `*p++` Indirection. Indirects through the pointer result of the expression 1. The result is the character that `p` originally pointed at, which is `'2'`.
3. `*p+++c` Addition. Adds result of 2. and `c`. Same as `*p++ + c`
4. `*p+++c&63` Bitwise and. Left hand operand is the result of 3. and right hand operator is an integer literal.

With full parentheses and sensible spacing: `(*(p++) + c) & 63`

---

Here is a formatted, well-formed version that produces no warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char**a) {
    const char* p = "25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-O?O&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_.";
    for(char c = a[1][0];
        *p;
        putc(c=((*p++ + c) & 63) + 32, stdout));
}
```

---

The string `"25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-O?O&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_."` is probably encrypted text. The program decrypts it if given the key as an argument. The first character of the first argument is used as the key.

A program to brute force the key:

> ```
>  #include <stdio.h>
>  int main() {
>      for (char i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
>          const char* p = "25YZ[<TT];SR^2]W+%'C^,X-O?O&__V[!;TT];D+ #.A3,A+ 4C,$!_.";
>          printf("%c: ", i);
>          for(char c = i;
>              *p;
>              putc(c=((*p++ + c) & 63) + 32, stdout));
>          putc('\n', stdout);
>      }
>  }
> ```

---

> What am I missing?

1. Order of operators 2. You're assuming that the key is alphanumeric.

Comment: Oh, I see - so I should have had `c = chr(((ord(p) + ord(c)) & 63) + 32)` instead of `c = chr(ord(p) + ((ord(c) & 63)) + 32)`. Thanks! I have it working now - much appreciated!